# Return a number that is not too small and not too big to use for operation?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, math, conditional-statements

I need help writing some javascript logic for a function that takes in an argument, `num` then declares the variables within the function:

```
const N = 21; 
const otherN = ( some logic );
const sum = ( N * otherN ) - num = some number greater than 21.
```

I’m wanting to write logic that will give me some number for my const otherN that I can use to run the operation, `sum`, with `num`, so that when `N * otherN` is subtracted from `num`, the sum wouldn’t be less than `N` BUT some number closer to `N`.

The desired output would be:

```
num = 288;
N = 24; 
otherN = (some logic ) ; // otherN chosen, 10

const sum = ( N * otherN ) - num = 48; // sum equals 48
```

An undesired output would be:

```
num = 288;
N = 24; 
otherN = (some logic ) ; // otherN chosen, 124

const sum = ( N * otherN ) - num = 48; // sum equals -2688
```

Hopefully, this makes sense. I imagine the `otherN` would also have to NOT be greater than num so there would be a condition of `< num`, but the otherN couldn't be something too large like if `num` was 200, `otherN` could NOT be 199.

Comment: In order to help you , please describe the variables in a better way .
For example : We have 4 Numbers . `a,b,c and d` where `d = (b*c) - a` with the following conditions : `a>0 ,  0<b<a`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help ?

```js
var num = parseInt(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
var N = parseInt(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

var otherN = parseInt((N + 1 + num) / N) + 1;

var sum = (N * otherN) - num;

console.log("num : " + num + "\nN : " + N + "\notherN : " + otherN + "\nsum : " + sum);
```